# Error while building apache spark

Tags: java, git, apache-spark, sbt, bigdata

While I am building Spark and write this command in cmd (sbt clean assembly) it starts building then it gives me this error... So What is the problem here?

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Jav
```

space

Use `last` for the full log.

Comment: The problem is simple: out of memory. Please post code so that we can say more.

Comment: I'm sorry, as Henri has asked 20 minutes ago, your question is not detailed enough for people to give you any answer to fix your error. [This is what stackoverflow recommends you to do in order for people to be able to help you](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the build tool `mvn` or `sbt` not having sufficient memory to build the *heavy* spark project

You may look at the SBT_OPTS or MAVEN_OPTS - depending on which one you used to build. Try one of these:

```
09:19:17/web $echo $SBT_OPTS
-Xmx3012m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
11:36:50/web $echo $MAVEN_OPTS
-Xmx1280m -XX:MaxPermSize=384m
```

And *yes*  sbt requires more memory than maven